# Select an Option from Right_click menu in selenium web driver in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to select an option from a right-click menu in selenium in python 2.7.

I am using web driver v ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 and selenium version 3.12.0 and I am so far succeeded in getting the right click. But, I am unable to select an option by scrolling down to the correct option within the right click.

```
action_chains.context_click(eleMenuShowtimes).perform() #for right-click

action_chains.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()    #for arrow down and enter 

action_chains.send_keys(u'\ue015').
send_keys(u'\ue015').send_keys(u'\ue007').perform() #for arrow down and enter in key code format

action_chains.context_click(eleMenuShowtimes).key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).
send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()    #combination of right click, arrow down and enter
```

I am able to get the right click but the arrow down and enter are not working in any of the codes. All codes that I am getting from searching are in Java format, but I need it in Python format. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do down arrow operation twice before clicking enter. Long back i also faced this issue i don't know the exact logic but clicking arrow-Down button twice worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that.It will do `right` click and click on the `first` item in the list.Let me know if it works.

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(eleMenuShowtimes).perform()
```

Comment: Hi, It's still stuck at right-click pop-up. It won't move down.